# jquery ajax post with & symbol

Tags: jquery

I am using jHTMLArea and I allow the user to type any character. I am also passing the values to a PHP page for processing but I have found that I cannot send the & symbol.

Is there a jQuery encode function? I am serializing the string but I think the PHP page is reading the & as a new parameter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `escape()` function to properly encode your data, when sending via HTTP

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the javascript function encodeURIComponent()  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp